# I am always getting invalid syntax when I am asking it to print

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am always getting an error message stating "syntax error" when I ask it to print a simple sentence. I do not know why, I am presently working on an AI. This is the code for which I am getting the error message.

`print ("what is your name ?")`

Comment: Maybe you are using python3? Then you would have to remove the space after `print`: `print("what is your name ?")`

Comment: Perhaps sharing the exact error message will make it easier to know if the error is coming from the print or some other part of the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the `print ("what is your name ?")` line.In Python 2.7 or Python 3,  works correctly. you may have to check syntax of  other lines of your code above to the print statement. you might have forgotten to close brackets or something else.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're using Python 2.7. In al python versions < 3, the print function doesn't need parentheses. Either install python 3 or use print like this: `print "what is your name ?"`. Also, in Python 3, there shouldn't be a space between `print` and `(...)`.